# PHP AJAX fields value from previous page

Tags: php, ajax

I have form in which fields come through AJAX and i fill those fields and send it to next  page. When i send it to next page their are two option either edit or submit. When i click on edit button value go to the first page and value display in fields but AJAX field and it's values not appear. How I show AJAX field and it's value in first page?

Comment: post the code you tried.

Comment: i did it through thick box but now i want to do it through ajax